# Racket - implementing the let* function using macro

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp, racket, let

I need to implement my_let* using **defmacro** which works similarly to let*, but while let* is expanded to a series of nested let calls (behind the scenes), my_let* needs to be expanded to a **single let** call, and use the **define** statement to define the arguments i get.

an example of using my_let*:

```
 (my_let* ((a 2)
 (b 3)
 (c (+ a b)))
 (+ a b c))
```

and the return value of this code should be 10. just as if it was use let*.
the code above will be expanded in **my_let*** to the following:

```
(let ()
 (define a 2)
 (define b 3)
 (define c (+ a b))
 (+ a b c))
```

I'm new to using macro, though i successfully written some macros, this one got me lost.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two issues: Do you really want to use `defmacro`, which Racket does have for compatibility reasons, instead of the (much easier) `define-syntax`, `syntax-rules`, and similar? Also, the expansion that you suggest isn't really the same as `let*` because `let*` allows you to shadow previous bindings whereas `define` does not. Are you ok with that?

Comment: @BrendanCannell in this case yes, as it is a part of an assignment (and a part of it is macros). i would still like to learn about the use of define-syntax. (maybe it is a part of the course that will be learned in the future).

Comment: Ok. Rather than someone just giving you the answer, maybe you can tell us what you've tried and what you're thinking so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @BrendanCannell as I mentioned above. this one's got me lost. I did write other macros successfully, but even using (define x y) for defining a variable is new to me, since we always used (let x y) for this purpose. In addition, i can't tell what the inner helper function should do here.

Comment: I cannot reasonably guess what went wrong in your definition since you failed to give it to us. Then the only answer can be to simply write the code for you. There isn't even anything to explain. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @law-of-fives I do know the code for this should be relatively short, and I honestly think I can learn from just reading the code if there's nothing to be explained here :).

Comment: A macro is basically just a function that accepts one s-expression, transforms it into a new s-expression, and returns the result. Notice that there's a pretty simple transformation from the input to the desired output: Each of the bindings is prepended with `'define`, and the resulting list of bindings is then prepended with `'(let ())` and appended with the body expression(s). If you can translate that into code, you're done.

Comment: @BrendanCannell: Internal definitions (that is definitions, as here, at the beginning of a let or lambda statement) do allow shadowing of previous bindings.  In R6RS and R7RS, an internal definition is for the most part (and leaving aside the obvious syntactic differences) indistinguishable from letrec*.

Comment: @ChrisVine That must be a difference between Racket and RnRS. Racket definitely gives you an error if you `define` a symbol more than once in an internal definition context.

Comment: @BrendanCannell: §4.5.4 of https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html suggests that every lambda expression (and therefore every let expression) can have its own set of initial internal definitions irrespective of whether the thing defined is also defined in some enclosing scope which is shadowed.  It would be very odd if it did not.

Comment: @ChrisVine I think you're misunderstanding me. I don't mean that `define` can't shadow bindings from outside the internal definition scope. I mean that it can't shadow bindings that were established earlier in the same scope, unlike how each binding in a `let*` can shadow the previous ones. Therefore Dul's macro definition of `let*` is not quite correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use `syntax-parse`. At the least don't even consider using `defmacro` in Racket.

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (my-let* stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_my-let* ([name:id e:expr] ...) body ...)
     #'(let ()
         (define name e) ...
         body ...)]))
```

The `name:id` means that `name` must be an identifier and `e:expr` means
that `e` must an expression. These simple annotations help syntax-parse
to give you better error messages.

Example:

```
(my-let* ((4 2)
          (b 3)
          (c (+ a b)))
         (+ a b c))
```

Here the DrRacket will color the 4 read and give the message:

```
my-let*: expected identifier in: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scheme way is using `syntax-rules`

```
(define-syntax my-let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ((binding expression) ...) body ...)
     (let ()
       (define binding expression) ...
       body ...))))
```

Using `defmacro` is more like making a procedure.

```
(define (my-let-fun* bindings . body)
  ...)
```

How it should work is like this:

```
(my-let-fun* '((a 1) (b 2) (c (+ a b))) "test" '(list a b c))
; ==> (let () (define a 1) (define b 2) (define c (+ a b)) "test" (list a b c))
```

If you have not called `my-let-fun*` in your implementation it's just changing it to a `defmacro` and you're done.

```
(defmacro my-let* (bindings . body)
  ...)
```

It's quite simple to do either with a helper to do recursion or `foldr` to do the bindings. Good luck!

Your `my-let*` will only work in `#lang racket` and perhaps `#!r6rs` and later. In R5RS you will get an error in this case:

```
(my-let* ((a 1) (b 2) (c (+ a b)))
  (list a b c))
; signals an error that a is undefined.
```

The reason is that it expands to something like this:

```
(let ((a 'undefined) (b 'undefined) (c 'undefined))
  (let ((tmp1 1) (tmp2 2) (tmp3 (+ a b)))
    (set! a tmp1)
    (set! b tmp2)
    (set! c tmp3))
  (list a b c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Between the error messages and some judicious use of the macro stepper I think it's hard to go too wrong here. The trouble is just making sure you've put things together right using either conses or unquote-splicing. I believe the standard practice in such macros is heavy use of quasiquote and unquote-splicing in order for the output to as closely match the intended statement as possible, otherwise the macro can become quite inscrutable. But I am not a `defmacro` expert.

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base)
         compatibility/defmacro)

(defmacro my-let* (binding-pairs . body)
  (define defines (map (lambda (bp) (cons 'define bp)) binding-pairs))
  `(let ()
     ,@defines
     ,@body))

(my-let* ((a 2) 
          (b (expt a 3)))
  (printf "a:~a\nb:~a\n" a b)
  (+ a b))
```